# Pandas get matrix of missing interactions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with following format:

```
user_id, item_id
0, 0
0, 1
1, 1
2, 1
2, 2
3, 0
```

Where each entry in the `df` means that `user_id` has purchased an item with `item_id` (for example user `0` bought item `0` & `1`)

How can I generate a data structure that would store the items not purchased by the users?

For the example above the expected result would be:

```
0: 2
1: 0, 2
2: 0
3: 1, 2
```

Naive approach would be to do something like this:

```
missing = dict()
all_items = set(df['item_id'].unique())
for user in df['user_id'].unique():
    user_items = set(df[df['user_id'] == user]['item_id'].values)
    missing_items = all_items.difference(user_items)
    missing[user] = missing_items
```

But this approach is very slow for large dataframes. Is there a more efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `df.groupby` within dict comprehension:

```
all_items = set(df['item_id'].unique())
missing = {i: all_items - set(g['item_id']) for i, g in df.groupby('user_id')}
```

---

```
{0: {2}, 1: {0, 2}, 2: {0}, 3: {1, 2}}
```